# simplify css for nested divs

Tags: css, html

I have a DOM like this:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='visual'>
    indent indicator
  </div>
  <div class='nomove'>
    text in this class is always left-aligned
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='visual'>
      indent indicator
    </div>
    <div class='nomove'>
      text in this class is always left-aligned
    </div>
    <!-- more container nesting possible -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is

```
.container .visual {
    margin-left:20px;
}
.container .container .visual {
    margin-left:40px;
}
.container .container .container .visual {
    margin-left:60px;
}
```

which has to be done for every depth level and is of course silly.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TMAXa/4/) (Updated: more structure, more lines of text)

Is there a simpler solution that maintains the tree-like HTML and has the same effect?

Comment: Will your `.nomove` text always take up the same amount of vertical space, i.e. be one line?

Comment: .nomove needs to be a block element with possibly many lines of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        margin-left: 20px;  
    }

    .nomove {
        position:absolute;
        left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    }

    .dummie {
        color:transparent;
        width: 100px;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="visual">indent indicator</div>
    <div class="nomove">text in this class is always left-aligned</div>
    <div class="dummie">text in this class is always left-aligned</div>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='visual'>indent indicator</div>
        <div class='nomove'>text in this class is always left-aligned text in this class is always left-aligned text in this class is always left-aligned text in this class is always left-aligned</div>
        <div class="dummie">text in this class is always left-aligned text in this class is always left-aligned text in this class is always left-aligned text in this class is always left-aligned</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The .nomove div is moved with position:absolute and left:0px to the left side. The dummie div makes a gap between two divs, because position:absolute has no height.

PS: Sorry for my english ;)

EDIT:

Now the dummie and the nomove div have the same text, the same width, but the dummie is transparent.

Comment: This won't work if the vertical height of a given `.nomove` changes (I had a similar thought - see my question to OP).

Comment: if the .nomove div has different heights, you should add the same text into the dummie element and make it transparent (color:transparent). The two divs (dummie and nomove) should also have the same width.

Comment: That's reasonable, but that's not what your answer indicates at present.

Comment: that's quite a hack, doubling page size (unless using JS which is OK) - neat ;) looks like the simplest solution so far

Comment: can I exclude .dummie from getting focus, or being selectable? (this is all inside a content-editable)

Comment: JS is an option. I guess with that, I can also calculate element.offsetHeight in .nomove before toggling absolute position. Choosing this as the best solution so far.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not a very elegant solution:

```
.container{
    padding:20px 0 0 20px;
}

.nomove {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/TMAXa/5/)

Comment: there's also the issue with multiple lines of text in .nomove - see my updated fiddle.

Comment: This won't work if the vertical height of a given .nomove changes (I had a similar thought - see my question to OP).

Answer (score 0):

You could remove some of the `container` classes and simply rely on three `visual` classes.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div class='visual1'>
    indent indicator
  </div>
  <div class='nomove'>
    text in this class is always left-aligned
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class='visual2'>
      indent indicator
    </div>
    <div class='nomove'>
      text in this class is always left-aligned
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class='visual3'>
        indent indicator
      </div>
      <div class='nomove'>
        text in this class is always left-aligned
      </div>
      <!-- more nested containers possible -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.visual1 {
    margin-left:20px;
}
.visual2 {
    margin-left:40px;
}
.visual3 {
    margin-left:60px;
}
```

Comment: that's not really any simpler though is it?

Comment: @davidb I would argue it is because if you add another container element within the dom structure you do not need to modify your css to account for the extra node.  Also if you remove a container element you will still have the same styling.  This markup is not reliant upon the structure of the DOM.  Where as the original css relied upon a particular nesting of elements within the DOM.

Comment: Agree, a declarative approach in the html is a good alternative. However, the tree data comes from the backend and the structure can be more complicated. Updating the fiddle to give an idea. I'd like to avoid calculating all those class names in the front end.

Comment: I'm actually trying to encode the indent information in the DOM structure - I hope that simplifies overall representation - see updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TMAXa/3/

Which is taking on from what @KevinBowersox said. but you dont need to use as much HTML code if you have an increment on the CSS.

```
<div class='visual1'>
    indent indicator
</div>
<div class='nomove'>
    text in this class is always left-aligned
</div>

<div class='visual2'>
    indent indicator
</div>
<div class='nomove'>
    text in this class is always left-aligned
</div>

<div class='visual3'>
    indent indicator
</div>
<div class='nomove'>
    text in this class is always left-aligned
</div>
```

Comment: I agree it would be nice to remove as much information from the DOM as possible. However, here I may have to put that logic into CSS (I don't know upfront the highest visualN. Also, a simple "delta-margin" would be better than assigning absolute margins to each visual class.). See updated fiddle

Comment: You will need to use some jquery or javascript to work out where the next visual class is and apply the margin that way.